# Intellij IDEA ignoring files run issue

Tags: intellij-idea

Hello all I am trying to run a programme using Intellij. The programme runs perfectly in Eclipse and Terminal. However using IDEA it seems to ignore 2 files.

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\data\def\items\ItemValues.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

There are no errors normally in Intellij. I just get this error upon running it. The file is there I have checked and path is correct. Intellij just seems to be ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Working directory` in `Run/Debug Configuration`, you need to change it to `$MODULE_DIR$` if you have multiple levels of maven modules.